# HTML5 Video does not load local video Ionic Android

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, video

I've got a problem with some code in Ionic.

I am developing an app on Ios and Android that needs access to the video.

The video is private and specific that is why I need to store them in the assets folder. 
Here is the problem, sometimes on Android, the video can not be loaded from this file and I have a GET error, it tries 30 times to get the video and then stop.

That means that whenever I play the video I get an Error saying: Uncaught promise the play() method was interrupted by a call to pause().

[Here are the request from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRdV6.jpg)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPcbC.jpg)

Above are the request and the error code.

Here is my HTML5 code :

```
<ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center ion-align-items-center">
    <video class="ion-no-margin" #video *ngIf="exercise?.video"
        playsinline loop preload="auto" [ngClass]="{'preview-video': !isExerciseStarted}"
        tappable (click)="onClickStartVideo()" [poster]="exercise.thumbnail">

            <source [src]="exercise?.video" type='video/mp4'>

      </video>
</ion-row>
```

And here is the TypeScript :

```
public onClickStartVideo() {
    const video = (<HTMLVideoElement>this.video.nativeElement);
    if (this.isVideoPlaying) {
        video.currentTime = 0;
    } else {
        video.currentTime = 0;
        video.play();
    }
    this.isVideoPlaying = true;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you don't need to write click method on video tag. If you like to play video from some external button you need to write click method else video tag handle everything by itself

Comment: well the thing is that this button is a toggle on the video. If you click again it calls a function to stop the video I modified a bit the code for this post but the real thing i'm worrying about is why it can not get items in the assets folder

Comment: I come back to my problem after finding a solution. I've investigated a bit and i saw that only the first request worked sometimes. I removed preload="auto" and changed to preload="none" and that corrected everything